# Does anyone know of an open source JSON Schema Metadata Repository?

Tags: json, git, repository, metadata, jsonschema

Does anyone know of an open source JSON Schema Metadata Repository?

We are looking for a tool that allows us to publish JSON Schemas for  use for API development.  It should have versioning capability, and ability to publish on a web server so that they can be reference by the $ref directive.  Integration with GIT would be a bonus.

Thanks

Comment: by "publish JSON schemas" do you mean something like [this](https://github.com/lbovet/docson)? Or would a standard [api documentation template](https://github.com/tripit/slate) work?

Answer (score 0):

Would the "Schema Repo" fill the bill?
https://github.com/schema-repo/schema-repo